# how to open camera from native application in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, image, editing

I want to write a app in which I open the camera take a picture and then edit the picture.I want to apply some cool effects on image as well.something like image editing...does some one knows a good or I say best approach to achieve this?

I want to know that is open-gl necessary to create an aap like image editing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is truly easy. Your code will be in a subclass of `UIViewController`, let this class conform to the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` protocol, this allows your controller to receive images from the camera and/or users library.

Now you have to create and display a `UIImagePickerController`, this view controller can be used for both selecting images from the users library, and taking images/video with the camera. Implement something like this:

```
-(IBAction)takePictureWithCamera {
  UIImagePickerController* controller = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
  controller.delegate = self;
  [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
  [controller release];
}
```

This will display the image picker, see documentation for `UIImagePickerController` for how to customize further if needed.

Next you need to receive the image the user picks, or takes with the camera. This is done by implementing the method `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` from the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` protocol.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)picker
    didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary*)info {
  UIImage* image = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
  // Do stuff to image.
}
```

And that is it.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [UIImagePickerController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) class. It's a view controller that you can present modally, and it lets you "pick" an image from the camera using the iPhone's native interface for taking photos.